# Single a single material across several objects with individual control

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Is it possible to share a single material across several objects but have control over some aspect of the material (e.g. factor on a fade node) on individual objects. Each object can be associated with an individual FCurve. I am currently building N identical materials for N objects, but its getting old. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Select the part of the material that you want to share and make it into [a group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/groups.html) with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. Use the group in each material with any custom nodes you may want for the object.

Using a group you can connect any inputs you want so that each material can use different values to customize the material for each object, while the nodes in the group stay the same.

[image: a group node]