# A single node that affect multiple meshes

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, color, groups

I have a lot of meshes of hair ( with their own node setup/uvs/textures/materials ) that forms a complete haircut.

How can i make a node , like a color ramp , that will affect all these meshes at the same time?

Comment: what about making a nodegroup and use this nodegroup for all your materials?

Comment: I don't know how to.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/91354/2214
https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/133208/2214
https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/193683/2214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just for an example, you can put nearly everything in your node group:

Add these two nodes:

[image]

Select both,

[image]

Choose "Make group"

[image]

Connect color to group output.

Press Tab.

Select your nodegroup and another color, add a mix node and connect like this:

[image]

Now add your nodegroup to all your materials.

If you change your nodegroup e.g. the scale, all materials will change as you want.

[image]